# I want to count in R how many rows I have that have no 0 value at all

Tags: r, selection, zero

I have a data set with 5908 rows (now the variables) and 5 columns (observations). The variables take the value 0.00 in some column.
I want to sort out the rows that do not have any zero values at all.

```
df <- read.delim2("permutation.txt")

# Randomly select 5 column names out of 60 (because I actually have 60 columns)
selected_column_names <- sample(colnames(df), 5)


# Select the 5 specified columns from the data frame
selected_data <- df[, selected_column_names]
```

I would like the rows that do not contain any 0.00 value at all to be sorted out.

Comment: Do you have missing values?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.  See the top of the [tag:r] tag page on information on how to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

Apply a function to each row and save the result into a variable.

```
selected_data$drop <- apply(testdf, 1, \(x) any(x == 0))
```

Then you can filter your dataset based on the variable. Like:

```
testdf[!testdf$drop, ]
```

It is also possible to count how many FALSE in drop if only the number is needed.